# XAML ListView ItemContainer Height

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, win-universal-app, uwp

I want to Change the `Height` of the `ItemContainer` and not the `Height`of the Item itself the Container is in a `ListView`

What I want to Change:

[image]

To Something like this:

[image]

The structur of the Code Looks like this:

```
 <ListView>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding A}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding B}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Hope for some help

Answer (score 9):

You need to change the `MinHeight` of all `ListViewItem` elements that appear in your `ListView`. You can achieve this by using a `Style`.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
    <TextBlock Text="World"/>
</ListView>
```

Using `Padding` with this method is also a good idea as you do not want each list view item to be *too thin*.

Comment: thanks for your quick anser but this doesn't work on my Items, i even set a minus value

Comment: Do you have any other styles that target `ListViewItem`? Is this example working in your project? Perhaps create a new project just to see if it works?

Comment: Now I konw why it didn't work ... because of the DataTemplat i had but now the binding doesn't work could you help me here again the binding is to the `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` and in the `Textblocks`  look like `Text="{Binding Name}"` and `Text="{Binding Adress}"` and both of them are in a Grid hope you can help me again ;)