# Set MinHeight of ListViewItem in C# (as opposed to XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33525753/939213) shows how to set the `MinHeight` of `ListView` items **from XAML**.

I can't figure out how to do this in C#. I tried looking for an appropriate argument for `imageCell.SetBinding()` and tried finding `MinHeight` as a property of `ImageCell`...

So - How do I do this in C#?

Comment: Create a style in C# instead of XAML, do all the other stuff he did but in C# instead of XAML, etc. etc. Or just do it in XAML.

Comment: Why is there a requirement for this XAML-without-XAML stuff?

Comment: @EdPlunkett `Create a style in C# instead of XAML` - That's exactly my question. This is what I have so far: `Style style = new Style(typeof(ListView));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter { Property = ListView.ItemTemplateProperty, Value = 30 });` Not much good, it seems.

Comment: It's a non-XAML Xamarin project.

Comment: OK, if you can't XAML, you can't. If you tried to create a style and apply it and it "seemed" not to be "much good", can you show us the actual code that didn't work for you?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I just did :(. I'm trying to emulate [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1729569/939213) answer, but apparently either I just don't know enough (hence my question), or perhaps it needs to be done a little differently in Xamarin. (I can't find a `MinHeight` to be used in a `Setter`'s `Property`.)

Comment: You mean you created a style object and didn't do anything with it? You need to make it the `ItemContainerStyle` for the `ListView`, like he did.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I was just describing its creation. There was one more line: `listView.Style = style;`. But it's targeting `ItemTemplateProperty` and I need `MinHeight` anyway.

Comment: @EdPlunkett `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` doesn't even exist in Xamarin.

Comment: In that case you may have a serious problem.

Comment: The example you are working from is not a Xamarin example. It is for UWP. The tags are: c#, xaml, listview, win-universal-app, uwp. A UWP ListView is not the same as a Xamarin Forms ListView, thus the available properties will be different. Here is the API docs for a Forms Cell: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Cell/ and a Forms ListView: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ListView/ . There is no MinHeight property, only a Cell.Height property and a ListView.RowHeight property.

Comment: @jgoldberger Thanks. Unfortunately Xamarin ListViews are way too dense on UWP. (They're fine on Android.) And setting a fixed height is a hack that can be broken depending on screen resolution and "text size" settings. Thanks again.